# Can I use an NSArray in NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, xcode

I was curious to know if I can use an NSArray within a NSMutableDictionary when declaring values for a variable. Because the app that I am coding required multiple instances of variable to equal about four or five floats. I don't want to have to write it like:

```
- (void)buildKeyMapping {
self.keyMapping = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:9];
[keyMapping setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:466.7] forKey:@"c1"];
[keyMapping setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:494.4] forKey:@"c2"];
[keyMapping setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:523.8] forKey:@"c3"];
[keyMapping setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:415.8] forKey:@"c4"];
[keyMapping setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:440.5] forKey:@"c5"];
```

I'm sure there is a way to declare a set of values to one variable but I am beginner at this language and I was hoping for a bit of help. Any tips?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can use any subclass of `NSObject`, including `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`, for an `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: this means that objects you want to use as keys in the dictionary must implement NSCopying. That's not required for values. +1

Comment: @Firoze: Quite correct. I was editing from the documentation and grabbed the wrong bit. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: So would I replace what is in the bracket with an array of either NSArray or NSMutableArray class?

Comment: @Luis: Yes, you can put the `NSNumber` objects into an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` and then just set the array as the object for some key.